# How to compare two number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm comparing two numbers in javascript. But it is not working perfectly
Below is my code

```
function selling_onchange(){
    var mrp = $('#mrp').val();
    var id = $('#selling_price').val();
    if(mrp > id){
        alert("mrp is greater");
    }else{
        alert("selling price is greater");
    }
}
```

If I am giving mrp is 100 and selling price is 20 then also it giving alert than selling price is greater.
If anybody knows solution than please help.

Comment: First convert them to numbers i.e. `Number(mrp) > Number(id)`

Comment: Like @Satpal said, you have to convert them to Numbers. .val() or .value returns a  string.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Satpal

Answer (score 2):

The  jQuery *eval()* function returns in string data type. So you need to convert the string into an integer or floating point values.

You can use the functions as follows.

```
var mrp = parseInt($('#mrp').val());
var id = paeseInt($('#selling_price').val());
```

Similarly,

```
var mrp = parseFloat($('#mrp').val());
var id = paeseFloat($('#selling_price').val());
```

Use parseFloat() to handle floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can not identify number datatype automaticall, you need to convert any value to integer or float

There are two function for that `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`

> The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.
>
> The `parseFloat()` function parses a string and returns a floating point number.
>
> The `Number()` function converts the object argument to a number that
>   represents the object's value.

```js
function compare() {

    var mrp = parseFloat($('#mrp').val());
    var id = parseFloat($('#selling_price').val());

    if (mrp > id) {
        $('#lbStatus').html("mrp is greater");
    } else {
        $('#lbStatus').html("selling price is greater");
    }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>MRP : </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mrp" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Selling price : </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="selling_price" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button onclick="compare()">Compare Value</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<label id="lbStatus"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.val()` method to get the value of the element then that value has `String` type and when you are comparing those values you need to explicitly convert that to the numeric type.

**USING +**

```
var mrp = +($('#mrp').val());
var id = +($('#selling_price').val());
```

**USING parseInt()**

```
var mrp = parseInt($('#mrp').val(), 10); //it is always a good practice to specify the redix
var id = parseInt($('#selling_price').val(), 10);
```

**USING parseFloat()** (if your values may contain floating point numbers)

```
var mrp = parseFloat($('#mrp').val());
var id = parseFloat($('#selling_price').val());
```

**USING Number()**

```
var mrp = Number($('#mrp').val());
var id = Number($('#selling_price').val());
```